# Change the color of the "screen" waves

Tags: javascript, user-interface, canvas, html2canvas

I been stuck on getting the waves to look just like I want. I'm trying to figure out how to get the base of the wave to be the color I need it. I can do my desired color but it blocks the background. I can not see anything behind it because I was using like a reflection. Maybe someone can figure it out cause I'm having difficulties getting it to work... I plan on making the wave drop and rise. Here is a link to the code pen: [HERE](https://codepen.io/RTarson/pen/ZVZVJW)

Here is where I have the vertical reflection:

```
var x = $.cx - $.length / 2 + $.length / $.count * i,
    y = height + $.simplex.noise2D($.xoff, $.yoff) * amp + sway;
    $.ctx[i === 0 ? 'moveTo' : 'lineTo'](x, y);
  }

  $.ctx.lineTo($.w, $.h); // -$.h - Vertically reflection
  $.ctx.lineTo(0, $.h); // -$.h - Vertically reflection
  $.ctx.closePath();
  $.ctx.fillStyle = color;

  if (comp) {
    $.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = comp;
  }

  $.ctx.fill();
```

My desired look for the waves is below:

[image: The way I want it to look]

Here is what I got with a successful transparent top, just not the right coloring:
[image: Not my desired look]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `screen` blending of the three colors generates a solid white color, so all the bottom of your canvas becomes white.

Here I simplified a lot the situation, with just 3 rectangles. Your bottom of canvas is my central white square:

```js
const c2 = canvas.cloneNode();

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'screen';
ctx.fillStyle = '#fb0000';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff8e";
ctx.fillRect(12,12,50,50);
ctx.fillStyle = "#6F33FF";
ctx.fillRect(25,25,50,50);
```

```css
body {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

So what we need, is a way to make this central square transparent so that we can draw our background behind.

To do this, we will need to draw our shapes at least two times:

- once in normal compositing mode, so that we get the full overlap.
- once again as `source-in` compositing mode, so that we get only where all our shapes do overlap.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawShapes(mode) {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = mode;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fb0000';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff8e";
  ctx.fillRect(12,12,50,50);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#6F33FF";
  ctx.fillRect(25,25,50,50);
}

drawShapes('screen');
drawShapes('source-in');
```

```css
body {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Now we have our overlapping area, we will be able to use it as a cutting shape in a third operation. But to do it, we will need a second, off-screen canvas to perform the compositing of the two states:

```js
const c2 = canvas.cloneNode();

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");

function drawShapes(ctx, comp) {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = comp;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fb0000';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff8e";
  ctx.fillRect(12, 12, 50, 50);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#6F33FF";
  ctx.fillRect(25, 25, 50, 50);
}
// first draw our screen, with unwanted white square
drawShapes(ctx, 'screen');
// draw it on the offscreen canvas
ctx2.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0)
// draw the shapes once again on the offscreen canvas to get the cutting shape
drawShapes(ctx2, 'source-in');
// cut the visible canvas
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'
ctx.drawImage(ctx2.canvas, 0, 0);
```

```css
body {
  background: #CCC
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

And voilà, our white square is now transparent, we can draw whatever we want behind our scene using the `destination-over` composite operation.

Comment: Thanks I will have to implement this!

Comment: @RTarson yes, you may have to refactor your code, the biggest issue with it is that you need to "remember" the noise generated to be able to draw twice the same paths. I leave it to you though since I thought that was a bit off from the question.

Comment: I am still messing around with this trying to find out the most feasible way of doing it... haha